# Skip certain indices while iterating each and maintaining group size

Tags: ruby, loops, ruby-on-rails-5

I have piece of code that currently takes an array of elements (in this case blog posts), sorts their numerical ID in descending order, puts them into groupings of 3, and iterates through each and every one of them.

I need to add a condition where if `blog.published` is `false` for any blog, do not display it and use the next blog.

Whenever a blog that has the published value set to `false`, the grouping will set the position in the grouping to `nil,` rather than filling it with the next blog entry, leaving some groupings with only 2 or 1 blogs on the view. I have attempted increasing the index by replacing each with `each_with_index` and iterating the index value when the condition is met, but this also yields the same issue. Here is my current code.

```
<% @blogs.order('created_at DESC').in_groups_of(3, false).each do |group| %>
   <div class="row pt-3">
      <% group.each do |blog| %>
        <% next if blog.published == false && current_page?(root_path) %>
           <%# Do View Stuff For Each Blog Here %>
      <% end #each %>
   </div>
<% end #grouping %>
```

Each grouping should always have 3 blogs and should skip over any blog that has the publication value set to `false`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@blogs = Blog.where.not(published: false).order('created_at desc').in_groups_of(3, false)`

PS. If you're doing `@blogs = Blog.all` in your controller, try not to build AR queries inside your view. Even queries aren't executed until you call it somehow, they should be fully-built in your controller method.

Comment: I think OP wants to *exclude* blog posts where `published` is `false`, so you want `where(published: true)`. Otherwise this is an excellent answer and a much better approach.

Comment: @Jordan you are absolutely correct! Thank you for the simple solution, I completely forgot about the .where operator and thanks for providing the proper convention!

Answer (score 0):

If I get the point, this is a possible solution. I'm using pure Ruby and a collection of hashes as example, but it should be easy to transpose it to Rails.

So, given the collection:

```
posts = [ {id: 1, pub: true}, {id: 2, pub: false}, {id: 3, pub: true}, {id: 4, pub: true}, {id: 5, pub: true}, {id: 6, pub: false}, {id: 7, pub: true}, {id: 8, pub: true}, {id: 9, pub: true}, {id: 10, pub: true}, {id: 11, pub: true}, {id: 12, pub: true}, {id: 13, pub: false}, {id: 14, pub: true} ]
```

Using [Enumerable#each_slice](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_slice) and [Array#reject](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/Array.html#method-i-reject):

```
groups_of_three = posts.each_slice(3).map { |group| group.reject { |h| h[:pub] == false } }
```

Printing out tho show the result:

```
groups_of_three.each { |group| p group }

# [{:id=>1,  :pub=>true}, {:id=>3,  :pub=>true}]
# [{:id=>4,  :pub=>true}, {:id=>5,  :pub=>true}]
# [{:id=>7,  :pub=>true}, {:id=>8,  :pub=>true}, {:id=>9,  :pub=>true}]
# [{:id=>10, :pub=>true}, {:id=>11, :pub=>true}, {:id=>12, :pub=>true}]
# [{:id=>14, :pub=>true}]
```